# How does return work in the code given below?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
Distance operator- ()  
{
 feet = -feet;
 inches = -inches;
 return Distance(feet, inches);
}
```

I am trying to learn operator overloading. The above code is used to overload the '-' operator. However I am not able to understad, how the return statement works here. What exactly happens? How is the object returned here?

The above code runs fine, but the one written below this statement doesn't. What is the error in this code?

```
Distance operator- ()
{
    Distance d;

    d.feet=(-feet);
    d.inches=(-inches);

    return d;
}
```

Comment: @puppy: what is the purpose of 'Distance(feet,inches);'? What exactly does it do?

Comment: This is also pretty bad code. Unary negation shouldn't change the operand.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `return`.

Comment: @user3734204: If you return 4, you return a temporary int (on the stack). If you return `Distance(feet,inches)`, you return a temporary Distance object created with it´s constructor which takes two numbers. That´s not complicated stuff, read a C++ book.

Comment: @user3734204: What is `d` in your second code?

Comment: @deviantfan: What is the error int the 2nd snippet that I have posted?

Comment: @user3734204: I´m asking you what d is. And the error message would be helpful too.

Comment: @deviantfan: Actually I am not getting syntax error. I am getting the incorrect output. The operator overloading function is not working. I am getting the same output before and after overloading.

Comment: its the second version that is correct. are you capturing the result?

Comment: like `Distance new_d = - old_d;`

Comment: @sp2danny: 2nd code snippet is not working. The result is same before and after overloading. Suppose i enter 5 & 10 (for feet and inches respectively), I am getting same 5 & 10 as output after using operator overloading function, where as I should  get -5 & -10.

Comment: if the second snippet isn't working for you, you are not using is right. are you capturing the result? functions return a result. the first version also incorrectly modifies the operand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the method should be const.  It's the  unary negation operator, which should return the "negative" version of its operand (the `foo` in `-foo`).

The easiest way to return the negative version of something is to make a new instance, and that's what your code does: it constructs a `Distance` object and returns it, using the negated values of the operand (which presumably is also a `Distance` instance).

The "return" statement behaves "as if" it were copying the newly-created Distance back to the caller, though the "Return Value Optimization" means no copy need actually be performed.  So you can think of it as constructing a Distance directly at the call site with the two arguments `(-feet, -inches)`.